# GLUU support for SAML URI binding

Tags: saml

I understand that GLUU uses Shibboleth for SAML. As going through the Shibboleth [Protocols and interfaces](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/ProtocolsAndInterfaces), there doesn't seem to be any support for SAML URI binding.

Does GLUU support URI binding? If so is there any document on its usage?